# GPIO cant control alll pins on raspberry-pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a python script which sets the output of my Raspberry Pi 3 like I want it (a led controller). but 3 pins are always on default set 1 and I can't set them to 0. I don't know why.

I tried to set them "manual" low but it wont work
console: gpio write pin 0

I looked in the directory /modules if sth reserves the pins but the list was empty.(maybe a service does?, but if yes which one?)

I wrote a .sh and .bash script to set them again to 0 on boot but it didnt work either.

I deactivated everything in the interfaces - raspi-config in the hope it uses a pin.( not ssh) failure.

I found a datasheet
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf page 102

There you can see the functions of a pin. Do i have to change them?

I need to use all of my pins.(0 to 27)

```
pi@pi3:~ $ gpio readall
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |  OUT | 0 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |  OUT | 0 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |  OUT | 0 |  7 || 8  | 0 | OUT  | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 0 | OUT  | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |  OUT | 1 | 11 || 12 | 1 | OUT  | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |  OUT | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |  OUT | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |  OUT | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |  OUT | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |  OUT | 0 | 23 || 24 | 0 | OUT  | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 0 | OUT  | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |  OUT | 0 | 27 || 28 | 0 | OUT  | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |  OUT | 0 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |  OUT | 0 | 31 || 32 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |  OUT | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |  OUT | 0 | 35 || 36 | 1 | OUT  | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |  OUT | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
pi@pi3:~ $ gpio write GPIO.0 0
pi@pi3:~ $ gpio write GPIO.1 0
pi@pi3:~ $ gpio write GPIO.27 0
pi@pi3:~ $ gpio readall
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 |  OUT | 0 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 |  OUT | 0 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |  OUT | 0 |  7 || 8  | 0 | OUT  | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 0 | OUT  | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |  OUT | 1 | 11 || 12 | 1 | OUT  | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |  OUT | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |  OUT | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |  OUT | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |  OUT | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |  OUT | 0 | 23 || 24 | 0 | OUT  | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 0 | OUT  | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |  OUT | 0 | 27 || 28 | 0 | OUT  | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |  OUT | 0 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |  OUT | 0 | 31 || 32 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |  OUT | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |  OUT | 0 | 35 || 36 | 1 | OUT  | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |  OUT | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | OUT  | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

I run out of ideas.
I hope my english is good enough to understand my issue.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

### First off, a couple things to note:

- **The pins that are powered are pins that are being pulled *high* by the pi. This means that the pin is normally high instead of low.**
- **The pdf you linked to is referring to the gpio pins as `BCM` mode.**

If you look at your output, the pins that are powered (in BCM mode)
are 16, 17, and 18.

Looking at the manual, it says that both gpio 16, and 17's function is reserved.

Gpio 18, though if I recall correctly, ***can*** be pulled low.
I vaguely remember having to bring one pin low for an ir receiver.

I'm not around my pi at the moment, but I believe you can bring gpio 18 low like this:

### gpiotest.py:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.output(18, False)
```